# Unable to edit top menu

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm making an e-commerce website using `Wordpress`. I'm using the `themify` theme. I've created a header for my landing page, which contains a colorful hero image.

Initially, I've made it

- `Background = transparent`
- `font color = white`
- `logo = white`

[image]

And I've set the sticky header also, with:

- `background color = white`
- `font color = black`
- `logo = colorful`

[image]

This is all good for the landing page.

But when I open another page, the initial state of header is :

- `Background = transparent`
- `font color = white`
- `logo = white`

[image]

But it doesn't fit in this case. I need to change header for other pages.

Help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your homepage should have a CSS body class of `home`. So you can make your header work for all other pages first and then create an exception for your homepage by targeting that body class.